# View based NSTableView with Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation

I have a view based NSTableView that contains cell views that have layers enabled. The NSTAbleView itself is also inside a view that has layers enabled.

For some reason I just get a quick flicker of the table view cells when it first loads, and I have to scroll them in and out to make them appear.

I just can't seem to figure out the reason why this is happening, are view based NSTableViews not supported with Core Animation (it just sounds strange to me if it isn't).

In general I have problems with Core Animation on OSX as opposed to iOS, and I have several cases where certain views just disappear as soon as I enable layer on their superviews.

After lots of googling I finally understood the difference in how the system treats layer backed views vs. layer hosting views, and it helped one of the problems I had, but not all.

Any input on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: NSTableView simply doesn't play nice with Core Animation layers. I haven't found a workaround. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can't find a good way to solve this issue either. But I realized just now that the problem I have is only when the cells load, and at that specific time I don't need layers to be enabled. I just need to have them enabled when doing a push animation (like the nav controller on iOS) and for that it is enough that I just enable them just before I do the animation, and disable it after again.